# Minimum value of of $a+b+\frac{1}{ab}$

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima

Okay so the question is:

> If $a,b$ are positive real numbers satisfying $a^2+b^2=1$, then the minimum value of $a + b + \frac{1}{ab}$ is?

The answer (without any reasoning) provided by the book is $2+\sqrt 2$. So I assume the reason would be that, if we draw a circle in a $a-b$ 2d plane then since $a, b$ are positive we take the points $(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2})$ and put in the equation so then we get that result.

But here is how I did it initially:
Use AM-GM inequality then
$a + b + \frac{1}{ab} \geq 3$

Then we can clearly see $3$ is smaller than $2+\sqrt 2$.

Am I missing something here??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing that there is no contradiction where you think there is one.

Comment: If that is the case, then there exist $a, b$ satisfying $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ such that $a = b = \frac{1}{ab}$.

Comment: The minimum from AM-GM is not achieved.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: as a function of $ab$:**

Write
$$f(a,b) = a+b+\frac{1}{ab} = \sqrt{(a+b)^2}+\frac{1}{ab}\\
= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2 ab}+\frac{1}{ab} = \sqrt{1 + 2 ab}+\frac{1}{ab} $$

since the restriction $a^2 + b^2  = 1$. So we see that $f$, under this restriction,  only depends on the product $ab$.

The maximum value that $ab$ can attain under the restriction $a^2 + b^2  = 1$ is given by AM-GM, as $1 = a^2 + b^2 \ge 2 ab$, hence $ab \le \frac12$.

Now note that the derivative
$$\frac{d \; f(ab)}{d \; (ab)}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2 ab}}- \frac{1}{(ab)^2} $$ is negative for all values $0 < ab \le  \frac12$. Hence the minimum of $f(a,b)$ under the restriction  $a^2 + b^2  = 1$ is attained at the maximum value for $ab$ which is  $ab = \frac12$. Then we obtain

$$f(a,b) =\sqrt{1 + 2 ab}+\frac{1}{ab} = 2 + \sqrt{2}$$

$\qquad \Box$

**Solution 2: with homogenization (with questions, see comments)**

You can homogenize this to:
$$f(a,b) = a+b+\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}$$

Now you can demand some value for $b$, e.g. $b = 1$, which gives a multiple of $f(a,b)$ which satisfies the condition  $a^2+b^2 = 1$ automatically, i.e.

$$F(a,1) = 2 a+1+\frac{1}{a}$$

By $F'(a) = 2 - \frac{1}{a^2} = 0$ you get at the minimum $a = \sqrt{1/2}$ immediately, which gives, for the original case, $b = \sqrt{1 - a^2} = \sqrt{1/2}$, and  for the minimum function value you get $a+b+\frac{1}{ab} = 2 \sqrt{1/2} + 2 = \sqrt{2} + 2$. $\qquad \Box$

Comment: To be truly homogeneous, would you not need $f(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann You're right. Nevertheless it works - why? As there are other answers to this question in another post, the case is closed ....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no contradiction between the two approaches... The minimum value of $2+\sqrt{2}$ is inded $\ge 3$. You can get the minimum by using the method of lagrange multipliers. The (local) minima will be stationary points of
$$
F(a,b,\lambda) = a + b + \frac{1}{ab} - \lambda(a^2+b^2-1).
$$

You can compute them and get the mentioned result.